# Formatting SQL query so only true values appear

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am trying to write a SQL query for work regarding orders. I only want to show orders with values that = 0.

The statement I am using is:

```
{SO1_SOEntryHeader.NonTaxableAmount} = 0
```

It shows a true/false value on my report. However, I only want the TRUE values to be visible on the report. What do I add to get this to work right? I am using Crystal Reports 2013.

Thanks!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx  True is 1.   False is 0  assuming data type is bit.  excerpt: "The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0."

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the `Section Expert` click on the section you want to display or not and in the right column where it say `Suppress` click on the button with the pencil. In there put your code.

Answer (score 0):

See this post here. It shows how to convert the "0" and "1" to "True" and "False" and different ways to show the data. It should give you what you need.